# Trying to scroll in terminal produces : 64;65;15M65;65;15M65 output instead

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

When I am trying to scroll up and down in my ubuntu `14.04`, my shell outputs this instead of scrolling:

```
64;38;17M64;38;17M64;38;17M64;38;17M64;38;17M
```

What is going on? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Same, but on Raspbian 10 (Buster) though. Happened while OS setup via SSH from macOS. Scrolling and clicking from the pad gave me the below.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ 65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M65;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M64;34;15M2;34;15M2;34;15m0;16;41M0;16;41m4;53;43M4;53;43m^C
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

### Cause

In my case, I had another terminal open to change the configs and see work.

### Fix

I closed all the terminals, re-log-in, do nothing but re-boot (`$ sudo reboot now`), then from the next login, it fixed the problem.